# Set datareader role in Azure SQL database, why do I get error?

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I am really struggling to add a Read-only User  with "Basic" authentication to my database.
The current user I'm logged in with is the DbAdmin, so I assume access rights should not be the issue.

I am running the below SQL statements, but the last one seems to give me the error

"Cannot alter the role 'db_datareader', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are executing the query on `master` database for which you do not have permission to add users to the `db_datareader` role in the `master` database.

The Server admin and Azure AD admin accounts have the following characteristics:

1. Do not enter the master database as the `dbo` user, and have limited permissions in master.
2. Are not members of the standard SQL Server sysadmin fixed server role, which is not available in SQL database.

Therefore, the LOGIN should be created in `master` database and USER should be added in `YourDatabase`. And then give `db_datareader` role inside `YourDatabase`.

Follow below steps:

1. In SQL Server Management Service (SSMS), login as a server admin and connect to the master database. Run below command.

```
CREATE LOGIN newLogin WITH PASSWORD = '<password>';
```

2. Now connect to database for which you need to create the user using above login and run below command.

```
CREATE USER [newLogin]
FROM LOGIN [newLogin]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;
```

3. Now run below command in the same database to alter `db_datareader` to the new user.

```
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [newLogin];
```

Refer below output image:

[image]

Comment: As the OP is using Azure SQL Database, seems they shouldn't be creating a `LOGIN` at all.

Comment: @Thom A, why do say this?

Comment: Because Azure SQL Databases are contained databases; `USER` authentication is normally the correct choice of authentication, not `LOGIN`.